# Node.js: Return data to client with pure html

Tags: node.js, authentication, server

i want to create a very simple login via node.js

My problem now is that if the user enters an incorrect password, i want to add a new label to the html saying "username or password incorrect" 
how can this be achieved using pure html only?

what i'm getting now is that i will just be redirected to /login which displays "missing username or password", but i want to stay on the login page.

another point is that i want to keep server-side redirect. client side redirection seems bad practice.

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  database.query("SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '" + req.body.username + "' AND password = '" + req.body.password + "')", function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      if(Object.values(data[0])[0] != 1) {
        res.status(400).send('Missing username or password'); // send this msg to html
      }
      else{
        res.redirect("main.html");
      }
      res.end();
    }
  });
});
app.listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the pure html part. Do you mean without javascript/ajax or template engine on server side?

I would use EJS for this, if I have to use form-post only. Otherwise, you can use ajax request.

The problem is you are returning an html result to the client. You have to return as following in case you use EJS;

```
return res.render('login.html', {errMsg:'Missing username or password'});
```

Comment: Yeah, i can't change the html directly without using a render engine like ejs, unfortunately.

Comment: by the way, if this code sample will work on production, keep in mind that, it is vulnerable to sql injection. such as anyone can send req.body.username as "blabla" OR 1=1;". use at least the default mysql.format method